# socket.io rooms: Can you have global variables specific to rooms?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I created a multiplayer game using node.js and socket.io

Right now the game runs through the default namespace.

In my server.js file, I have some global variables which I use for my game.

For example: 
Client selects a name "Karl" and that name gets stored in var nameVariable that is emitted to server.

client:

```
socket.emit("name", nameVariable);
```

On server side:

```
socket.on("name", function(nameVariable) { 

myGlobalArray.push(nameVariable);

if (myGlobalArray.length == numberOfClientsArray.length)
    io.sockets.emit("Name of all people", myGLobalArray);

});
```

The thing is, once I create rooms....is it possible for each room to maintain its own global variables?

Or do I have to change my game logic? And if so, what would I do? Like use a database or something to temporarily store?

Comment: Sure. Just add it as a property to the room.

Comment: @JonasWilms, how exactly would I do that? How do I access the room as a global variable specific to the room? Thanks!